# Is it possible to define a macro with the same properties as a begin form?

Tags: racket

More specifically what I am interested in is the one particular property of `begin` where definitions in its body added to the surrounding scope. E.g.

```
(begin (define a 1)
       (define b 2))
(+ a b) ; 3
```

It would be reasonably simple to define a new macro `my-begin` that is translated to a standard `begin`, but in my particular use case I need a list of all identifiers that are being bound in the begin, such that I can introduce/use them elsewhere.

Being more specific as to what I want to achieve: I am figuring out how to build a `PAR/AND` operator that evaluates two branches at the same time (or at least give the impression, given the context). The branches may contain blocking operations. The `PAR/AND` itself returns once both branches return. Any definitions become available in the outlying scope. For example:

```
(PAR/AND     
  (define a (do-something))       ; branch 1
  (define b (do-something-else))) ; branch 2
(+ a b)
```

I'm not quite certain yet how to implement it (since I have some extra stuff to worry about), but making `a` and `b` available outside the scope of `par/and` is definitely something that needs to happen at some point.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're probably right. I have added some more context to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have skipped the part about `define` totally and just made sure the expression are done in parallel and then when the threads are joined use `values`. In racket you have `define-values` where you can bind multiple values to global names and it can be used to name the values you have computed:

```scm
(define-values (a b)
  (parallel/values (do-something) (do-something-else)))
(+ a b)
; ==> 1337
```

`paralell/values` need to be syntax here, but since the expressions themselves are thunks you could in fact keep is a procedure that takes thunks:

```scm
(define-values (a b)
  (parallel/values do-something do-something-else))
(+ a b)
; ==> 1337
```

As you see this does not require a customized `begin` at all. I expect the expressions in parallel would introduce closures that will affect `define` so this circumvent that can of worms as well. `define-values` is **the actual `define` primitive**  in racket if you look at full expanded programs from the macro expander with macro hiding disabled.

Comment: I had not looked at the problem from this angle before, and would not have thought about using `define-values` in this manner. This is absolutely the "schemey" way to tackle the problem. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Yep, I was about to suggest this too.

Answer (score 1):

There are complicated ways to do this, but it looks like there's an easy way as well: can't you just have your `PAR/AND` macro expand into a `begin` ?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure whether that is possible given the goal. If I wanted actual concurrency for the branches then `PAR/AND` would spawn two threads to compute the branches, and basically synchronize them. `begin` doesn't help me here. The sort of blocking operation that may occur in the branches is actually more of a simple "wait until an event is received", so I can probably wrap a branch in a lambda that is executed once the required events are received. Would it be possible to provide a 'clean' environment and after execution check which bindings have been added?